# C++ GUI for Executable JAR

Tags: java, c++, windows, visual-c++

I have an executable JAR which runs in the command line.  I would like to create a GUI for this program using VC++ for windows.  Is there any way to 'hook into' the Java thread from the native C++, or launch the JAR from within the C++ thread?  I have looked at the JNI, but it appears that the Java needs to be written to take this functionality into account.  At the moment, I do not have the capability to modify the pre-compiled JAR.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The java only needs to be written with JNI functionality if you want to call C++ from Java. If you want to call Java from C++ it will work fine without any changes to the JAR. If you look at the source code to java.exe you can see an example of this.

Look at around lines 540-610 in [the java.exe source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/tools/launcher/java.c)

Comment: Thanks Dan, that's just what I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do with it? The easy way to simply launch would be to use the system() call, which can call any executable file, including .bat ones. A more complicated approach would have them be a client-server application and talk via localhost (example being a lot of network-based daemons like IRCd)